# excel macro not working for autofill to various rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro.

```
LR = Range("Y3333333").End(x1Up).Row
Range("C3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Y3:Y" & LR)

LR = Range("C3333333").End(x1Up).Row
Range("C3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("R3:R" & LR)

LR = Range("C3333333").End(x1Up).Row
Range("C3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B3:B" & LR)

LR = Range("C3333333").End(x1Up).Row
Range("C3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:A" & LR)
```

My number of rows varies each time I run this.  These (4) columns have nothing in rows 1 or 2.  Row three is a formula that I want to copy to the last column.

Column C is the only column that will always have information in it all all times for all lines.

Comment: 1.  the max rows are 1048576 .  2 It is `xlUp` not `x1Up`

Comment: So what is the issue you are having?  What is your Question?

Comment: Sorry!  I am trying to autofill columns Y, R, B, and A, based on the formula in row 3 of each of the respecting columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
Dim LR As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your Worksheet name
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row
    .Range("Y3:Y" & LR).FillDown
    .Range("R3:R" & LR).FillDown
    .Range("B3:B" & LR).FillDown
    .Range("A3:A" & LR).FillDown
End With
```

Comment: It tells me invalid or unqualified reference.

Comment: It highlights the .rows

Comment: @BBB see edit, that's what I get for typing in the answer and not vbe first.

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (more common) way of writing it is:

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Activesheet.Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
Range("C3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Y3:Y" & LR)
```

This would work in any sheet (also compatibility mode), and you do not need to autofill anymore

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, please move this to comments or edit your answer to properly answer the question at hand

Comment: @Maldred how do you know it does not answer the question?  There is no Question.

Comment: @ScottCraner Based off the title, I'm sure it's safe to assume that he's trying to fix the autofill; as you mentioned in the comments of the typo

Comment: This answer and my comment fix the same problem.  This just does it in a different method. @Maldred

Comment: Not sure if I understand? You mentioned of a typo (`xlUp`) and in Pierre44's original answer (before the edit) he had fixed the issue of using the last row. "*Row three is a formula that I want to copy to the last column*" - With this method it will count the last used cell in that column. What he's looking for is to auto-fill to the very end, am I correct?

Comment: You are correct sorry missed that.  I was so intent on the typos that I missed the range errors.  @Maldred  Pierre LR should be looking in Column C and The autofill should be `Range("Y3").Autofill...`

Comment: I am not sure, he looked first in the column Y and then in Column C. I edited to just give an example of how to correct it. I think BBB did a typo and didn t intend to look in the column C at the end either.

Comment: @ScottCraner No worries! Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't we trying to fill data into the very last row? Seems to me like the OP wants data filled to the very end of the spread sheet with this macro... Pierre44's answer would only fill to the end of `Range("C")` last used cell

Comment: @Maldred no Op wants it filled to the last used row in column C: `Column C is the only column that will always have information in it all all times for all lines.`  At least that is how I interpret it.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ahhh yes, you're right! Missed that, thanks :)