# Excel: How to make formulas update with a column length that varies

Tags: excel, csv

First off, apologies if this has been asked before. I struggled to find this being asked previously so here it goes:

I have formulas calculating incoming data from .csv's. The problem is the formula will only calculate the length of the original csv with its number of rows. The csv's coming in vary greatly in number of rows. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Thanks,
J

Comment: Please provide the formulas you are using.  It is hard to answer as some formulas will need different approaches.

Comment: Most of the formulas are simple arithmetic, sums, multiplication, division. I do have some array formulas for histograms, more specifically the frequency formula that counts the entire column. For example: =FREQUENCY(D3:D98,P25:P29) where the D column should be the entire column length.

Comment: Well I gave you about as generic an answer as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=SUM(B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B,0)))
```

This will sum all the cells starting in B2 to the last cell with numbers in Column B.

```
=CONCAT(B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",B:B,0)))
```

This will concatenate all the cells from B2 to the last cell with text in it.

To find the last cell regardless of whether number or text:

```
INDEX(B:B,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH("zzz",B:B,0),0),IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99,B:B,0),0)))
```

---

One note, most standard formula have no detriments to full column references, Like COUNTIF(S),SUMIF(S),...

Array formulas and Array like formulas (SUMPRODUCT,AGGREGATE) need to limit the references to the data set and using the above methods will allow the dynamic use of the data set.

---

Edit:

You Frequency formula:

```
=FREQUENCY(D3:INDEX(D:D,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH("zzz",D:D,0),0),IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99,D:D,0),0))),P25:P29)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Scott. Does this work when calculating on different sheets? For example I tried: 

=MEDIAN('Data from CSV'!D3:INDEX(D:D,MATCH(E1+99,D:D,0)))

and receieved an error "#N/A".

Comment: Yes but you need to add the sheet to all the `D:D` : `'Data from CSV'!D:D`, but Median is one of those that you can use the full column so `=MEDIAN('Data from CSV'!D:D)` works just as quickly as trying to limit the reference.

Comment: One follow up I have is now I have some calculations that row by row for the raw data coming in from csv. Is there a way to code the formula to autocomplete these column calculations with the changing row numbers? The current solution is to just double click the last cell in each column but there has to be a better way

Comment: Sure there is, it is called VBA.

Comment: See my answer for this question to give you an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596273/excel-macro-not-working-for-autofill-to-various-rows/47598416#47598416

Comment: Ahh man, ok. Time to actually learn the real Excel, haha. Thanks.

Comment: Following that answer, I was able to successfully create a macro, thanks Scott!

Answer (score 0):

You can change all the formulas to "D:D" in order to count the entire row. For example: "=countif(D:D,"*")" Will count everything in column D, you can use similar functions for other math operations as well.

You could also use VBA to dynamically count the number of rows, and then use that number in your formulas, but that is a whole other topic/conversation/question.

Comment: Be careful with full column references, not all formulas are optimized, any array formulas or array type formula(and there are many) will slow the calculations down and may even crash excel if too many are used.  Blanket statements of "Use full column references" is not appropriate in all cases.

Comment: Thanks, Issel and Scott for the further clarification. I used the full frequency formula per Scott's answer and it's working great, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've now ran into a problem with plots. I've used for the y values in the chart to be: ='Data from CSV'!$D:$D but I need it to always start at D3, not D1. How do I do this in the Edit Series dialog box within the plot in excel?

Comment: Is the problem it gives an incorrect count? If d1 and d2 are consistently adding +2, you can subtact 2 in the formula t o counter that.